# Add Customize Image launching the app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i touch my app in iPHone Simulator first black page will come for few millin seconds then out page will come. how should i add images instead of that black page. Please help me out?

Regards
Sri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an image by saving a file called Default.png in your project. This should be 320x480 px in size and will appear while your app is starting up.

[This page in the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) tells you about all the files you will need.

Answer (score -1):

1. you need a full-screen file (320, 480) (The file needs to be .png).
2. you need to rename your file to "Default".
3. you need to put the file into your "resources" in your project.
4. type this into the "applicationDidFinishLaunching" function in your "AppController.m":

   sleep(1);

1(second) represents how long your app is going to show your splashscreen.

If you have problems with that watch this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQwFLaAv5Zs

Comment: -1 for delaying the launch time needlessly for 1 second.  From the Apple docs linked by dean: "Because users are likely to switch among applications frequently, **you should make every effort to cut launch time to a minimum**, and you should design a launch image that downplays the experience rather than drawing attention to it."

Comment: Dude, what's your problem with that 1 second??? He wanted an image instead of that black page and i showed how to keep that image on the screen for a bit longer.